# How can I optimize this double-loop over an array using numpy?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

This code is quite slow in Python. How can I optimize this using numpy. The array m and z are already numpy arrays but I assume I need to vectorize this somehow though I can't find an example where the vectorized function also has access to the value coordinates.

```
for i in xrange(states):
    for j in xrange(states):
        if i != j and z[i, j] != 0 and m[i, j] < 0.0:
            m[i, i] += m[i, j]
            m[i, j] = 0.0
            z[i, j] = 0
```

Comment: what are you doing here? Setting m[i,j] += m[i,j] and then setting m[i,j] = 0??

Comment: Sorry, typo. It has been fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate your code to vectorized Numpy using arrays of indices:

```
import numpy as np

i, j = np.indices([states, states])
bool_index = (i != j) & (z != 0) & (m < 0.0)
z[bool_index] = 0
```

But since you already know what `i != j` will evaluate to, it's faster to just use a diagonal array. This also makes it easier to do the slightly awkward operation on `m`:

```
I = np.eye(states, dtype=bool)
bool_index = ~I & (z != 0) & (m < 0.0)

m[I] += (bool_index * m).sum(axis=1)
m[bool_index] = 0.0
z[bool_index] = 0
```

Note that the `&` operator does `np.bitwise_and` and not `np.logical_and` but they're equivalent in this case, because all operands are Boolean arrays.

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed a typo in the code. How can I leverage this for the operations on m?

Comment: @JonasKlemming: It's included in the edit to my answer. The multiplication by a Boolean array and subsequent summation seems a bit inefficient, but can't think of a better way right now.